# Flutter: animate a list without AnimatedList

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How can you animate a removal of an element from the list?

The element is deleted on removal, and I don't want to do some hokus pokus to prolong its life.

AnimatedList should not be used.

Comment: try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html

Comment: If you delete an element, it doesn't stay on widget tree, that is the problem. No animation can be done on or after dispose.

Comment: That's okay.. I found a solution..